# Magento: Same price but different tax for oversea customers

Tags: magento

I'm configuring a Magento site for international sales. My requirement is to calculate tax based on the geographical location of the user but the final price of the product will remain same.

Tax is applicable to local customers only. Overseas customers will get tax-free product. Whatever be the tax amount, the final price will be fixed for all the customers.

An example:

I want to sell a Item A for $100.
Our local Tax is 10%.

- So local customers pay  $90.91 + $9.09 of tax
- Oversea customers will pay $100 + $0 of tax.

Is there anyway to configure this in Magento?
Because after having tried in Magento many times, I can only make

- local customers paying  $90.91 + $9.09 of tax,
- but overseas customer always pay $90.91 + $0 of tax (not $100).

Comment: I too require this @ntuan16 - did you ever manage to achieve this?

Comment: +1 , did you ever get anywhere on this?

Answer (score 2):

Well, suppose all displaying price including Tax: 10% for local, free tax for overseas (decided by shipping address)

Create one Tax Zone & Rate rule for your country, like Austrlia with 10% Tax.

The key set is the "Enable Cross-Border Price Consistency" (Dashboard > System > Configuration > Sales > Tax > Calculation Settings > Enable Cross Border Trade )

When set it as Yes

Notes: Merchants operating across regions and geographies can show their customers a single price. Pricing is clean and uncluttered regardless of tax structures and rates that vary from country to country.

```
- Local customers pay $90.91 + $9.09 of tax
- Oversea customers will pay $100 + $0 of tax.
```

When set it as No

```
- Local customers paying $90.91 + $9.09 of tax,
- Overseas customer will pay $90.91 + $0 of tax (not $100).
```